# How to Consolidate Multiple rows to one Row in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have a data in one of the table like this. Since the A column is same for all the rows i need to consolidate the the "J" Column data into single row. Could you please let me know how to write the sql query to achieve this in oracle?

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I     J
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset#6076,Amount: $29.02       
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset #6077,Amount: $28.9       
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset #6078,Amount: $50.64      
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset #6079,Amount: $18.84      
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset #6080,Amount: $18.84      
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset #6081,Amount: $18.83      
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset #6082,Amount: $58.65      
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset #6083,Amount: $13.19      
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset #6084,Amount: $13.19      
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset #6085,Amount: $13.19      
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset #6086,Amount: $240.52     
03494   42934.24784 SPPT    Y   1           Property Tax Assessment 42736   
Asset #6087,Amount: $135.98
```

I have wirtten the below query to accommodate this. But the problem is it is 
taking too much time to retrieve. Is there anyother way i can make it work 
faster?

```
select lse_id app_lse_s,
       sysdate dt_ent_s,
       'SPPT' note_type_s,
       'Y' prcs_c,
       '1' prio_c,
       '   ' from_s,
       '   ' to_s,
       'Property Tax Assessment' note_title_s,
       lien_dt info1_s,
       LISTAGG('Asset #' || SG.AST_ID  ||  ',' || 'Amount: $' || 
                SG.ASES_PRT_1_AM , ',')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SG.AST_ID,SG.ASES_PRT_1_AM) info2_s
from   nmac_ptms_notebk_sg SG
where  lse_id = '     03494'
group by lse_id,
         lien_dt;
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I treid that. But still it is coming in multiple rows. Any other way?

Comment: you have different  I column too ..

Comment: Some how i managed to write the below query. The problem is it is taking so much time for retrieving. Is there anyother way i can make this work fatser? I made the edit in the original question. Can someone help me out on this?